# How to set the default collection of checked boxes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For a collection of checkboxes, how would I set the default checked boxes for multiple items? For example the way I'm thinking, when the page reloads, it should have three items checked, because the method `Country.select_countries` returns three countries.

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :countries do |form| %>
  <%= form.input :country_ids, as: :check_boxes, collection: Country.all.order('name ASC'),  checked:  Country.select_countries || []%>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set default values of `country_ids` for an object:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :countries do |form| %>
  <% f.object.country_ids = Country.select_countries if f.object.country_ids.blank? %>
  <%= form.input :country_ids, as: :check_boxes, collection: Country.all.order(:name) %>
<% end %>
```

This also can be set in controller or a model.